# Extending Ecma Script apis

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

So i have a react-native project and i was thinking of extending the parsefloat function.

I was hoping if there is a way one could extends the parsefloat function and each time the parsefloat function is called anywhere in the project it runs the local implementation.

Answer (score 4):

> each time the parsefloat function is called anywhere in the project it runs the local implementation

Since it sounds like you want `parseFloat` by itself to refer to your new function, what you're looking to do is *overwrite* the native `parseFloat` function. Although it often isn't a good idea to change globals like that, it's quite possible: first save a reference to `<global>.parseFloat`, then assign a new function to `<global>.parseFloat` that does whatever you want it to. For example, the following snippet overwrites `parseFloat` with a function that does almost the same thing, except that it returns the parsed number plus one:

```js
((global) => {
  const { parseFloat } = global;
  global.parseFloat = (val) => {
    return parseFloat(val) + 1;
  };
})(this);
console.log(parseFloat('2'));
```

Comment: Ok but where do i declare this function because the project has many different classes and modules.

Comment: And yes this is a react-native project not necessarily running in a browser.

Comment: @AmolGupta Anywhere you want, you just have to run it once, it's not really connected with the rest of the code, after all

Comment: @AmolGupta—there is no global declaration, it is assignment of a new function to *parseInt*, so it needs to be executed before your first call to *parseInt* where you expect the modified behaviour.

Comment: @AmolGupta When answers solve the problem you're having, consider marking them as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Comment: Just a question are we suppose to de-structure the window object or global ?

Comment: @AmolGupta Oh, that's right, definitely `global`, not `window`, forgot to edit that too